# A proof in Spivak on integration.

Tags: calculus

The theorem states

> If $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ $\iff$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that
>
> $$U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$$

The proof is on page 220. I believe I  have the 2nd ed of the book.

One of the steps really confused me in which he writes

> "$\inf \{ U(f,P')\} - \sup\{ L(f,P')\} < \epsilon$, since this is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, it follows that $\inf \{ U(f,P')\} = \sup\{ L(f,P')\}$

I do not understand how this follows, how did this become an equality?

Comment: So he is saying that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) - L = 0 \implies f(x) = L$?

Comment: Actually why is the LHS bounded below by 0?

Comment: No that's exactly what is in the book. Though the inf of a set is a number and so is the sup. So we are really subtracting numbers here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a cute strategy in analysis: to prove that $x = y$, you instead prove that $|x - y| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.  Because if $x \neq y$, then taking $\epsilon = |x - y|$ would falsify the inequality.  In your case, $x = \inf U(f,P')$ and $y = \sup L(f,P')$.

In your question, the absolute values are omitted because $x > y$ already; this is because we always have $U(f,P') \geq L(f,P')$ for the same partition, which is the intuition behind the use of "upper" and "lower" in the names of these quantities.

Comment: But he didn't use absolute values at all

Comment: Absolute values aren't needed because the difference in question is non-negative.  All the numbers $U(f,P)$ (as $P$ varies) are $\geq$ all the numbers $L(f,P)$, so the infimum of the former is at least as large as the supremum of the latter.

Comment: Can expand on the $\epsilon = |x - y| $ part a bit? I am still have trouble seeing the conclusion

Comment: @sizz: Suppose you know that $|x-y| \lt \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. If $x \ne y$, you can take $\epsilon = |x-y|$ (because $x-y$ is not $0$), and you get $|x-y| < |x-y|$, a contradiction which came from assuming $x \ne y$.

Comment: Oh I see, he omitted a lot of steps here...

Comment: It's better than what you wrote, Ryan. For any two partitions, $P$ and $Q$ you have that $U(f,P) \geq L(f,Q)$. Because there is some common refinement $R$ of both $P$ and $Q$ and hence we must have that $U(f,P) \geq U(f,R) \geq L(f,R) \geq L(f,Q)$.

Comment: More generally, if $a < b+ \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, then $a \leq b$. This is used all the time in analysis.

Comment: So basically we have $0 < |x - y| < \epsilon $ for all $\epsilon$. Then we choose $\epsilon = |x - y|$ to get a contradiction to the fact that $x \neq y$? Now I actually don't understand the point of the theorem.

Comment: In the theorem, $x$ and $y$ depend on $\epsilon$ so it doesn't follow that $x = y$ (after getting $\epsilon$, you have to find an appropriate partition); the theorem is basically saying that the limit of Riemann sums exists.  However, in the step that you asked about, you've got some partition $P'$ already and the claim is that some quantities depending on its upper and lower sums are equal; this is proved by showing that their difference is less than every positive number, hence zero. (Since otherwise it would be positive, so not less than itself.)

Answer (score 1):

This is called a Darboux integral and to show that $\inf \{ U(f,P')\} \geq \sup\{ L(f,P')\}$  you first have to show that for a refinement $P'$ of a partition $P$ you always have $$U(f,P) \geq U(f,P') \geq L(f,P') \geq L(f,P).$$ Then to show that all the upper integrals are bigger than all the lower integrals you can use the fact that for any two partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$ there is always a partition $P'$ that is a refinement of both of them, $P' = P_1 \cup P_2$ for example.

Now assume we have $0 \leq \inf \{ U(f,P')\} - \sup\{ L(f,P')\} < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ as assumed in the question. That doesn't leave room for the difference to be anything other than zero since $\epsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily small.

Comment: How did you turn a strict inequality into an ordinary inequality?

Comment: @sizz Typo. Thanks for pointing it out, I've fixed it.